# Facebook Log in is showing a blank page on facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api

I use Facebook to log in to my site. If you click "Sign in with Facebook" on [Timelino](http://www.timelino.com/), it just takes you to a blank page on Facebook.

It takes you to this page `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=1530718867141832&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.timelino.com%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=email&state=08dcadd665ebc15f81553fa81e288bd81c4d712f684bfde0`

What can cause this?

Comment: You should be getting at least an error message if this was an error on your part; in cases where you just get a 500 Internal Server Error from FB, you should file a bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Bug filed: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/938452396170896/